# Cuda - Big array initialization

Tags: c, cuda

What is the best approach (efficiently) to initialize a large array of integers for the gpu? I need to assign 1 for first two elements and 0 for other (for Sieve of Eratosthenes).

1. cudaMemcpy
2. cudaMemset + set value of 2 first elements in kernel
3. initialization direct in kernel
4. sth else

**Note:** Array size is dynamic (n is passed as an argument).

My current version:

```
int array = (int*) malloc(array_size);
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_array, array, array_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
kernel<<<10, 10>>>(dev_array);
```

I would be grateful for an example.

Comment: Have you considered `calloc` (which zero initializes) instead of `malloc` and then just the first 2 elements to 1 (like you do) ?

Comment: @Blue Moon, thx for idea, but calloc operation is not available for CUDA programs.

Comment: Better to use `cudaMemset` instead of loop.

Comment: @haccks, ok but what about the first two elements? Initialize it in single thread?

Comment: For first two elements: `array[0] = array[1] = 0;`. and then `cudaMemset(&array[2], 0, array_size * sizeof(int));`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to directly initialize `__device__` array on GPU if it has constant size by adding following declaration at file scope (that is, outside of any function):

```
__device__ int dev_array[SIZE] = {1, 1};
```

The remaining elements will be initiliazed with zeros (you can check PTX assembly to be sure of that).

then, it can be used in kernel like:

```
__global__ void kernel(void)
{
    int tid = ...;
    int elem = dev_array[tid];
    ...
}
```

In case of variable size, you can combine `cudaMalloc()` with `cudaMemset()`:

```
int array_size = ...;
int *dev_array;

cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_array, array_size * sizeof(int));
cudaMemset(dev_array, 0, array_size * sizeof(int));
```

then set first two elements as ones:

```
int helper_array[2] = {1, 1};
cudaMemcpy(dev_array, helper_array, 2 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Beginning with compute capability 2.0 you can also allocate whole array directly within kernel by the `malloc()` device function:

```
__global__ void kernel(int array_size)
{
    int *dev_array;
    int tid = ...;

    if (tid == 0) {
        dev_array = (int *) malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));
        if (dev_array == NULL) {
            ...
        }
        memset(dev_array, 0, array_size * sizeof(int));
        dev_array[0] = dev_array[1] = 1;  
    }
    __syncthreads();

    ...
}
```

Note that threads from different blocks are unaware of barrier synchronization.

From the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations):

> The CUDA in-kernel `malloc()` function allocates at least `size` bytes
>   from the device heap and returns a pointer to the allocated memory or
>   `NULL` if insufficient memory exists to fulfill the request. The
>   returned pointer is guaranteed to be aligned to a 16-byte boundary.

Unfortunatelly, the `calloc()` function is not implemented, hence you need to memset it anyway. Allocated memory has lifetime of CUDA context, but you can explicitely call `free()` from this or subsequent kernel at any time:

> The memory allocated by a given CUDA thread via `malloc()` remains
>   allocated for the lifetime of the CUDA context, or until it is
>   explicitly released by a call to `free()`. It can be used by any other
>   CUDA threads even from subsequent kernel launches.

With all that said, I wouldn't mind that much about supplementary `cudaMemcpy()`, since it's just two elements to copy and it would *likely* take less than 0.01% of the total execution time (it's easy to profile). Choose whatever way that makes you code clear. Otherwise it's a [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: thx nice idea, but I hasn't constant size. I'm sorry that i didn't write this before.

Comment: @Bakus123: Edited again with some note.